# Grabbing the Image URL with different src tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Currently My code works fine and I am able to get the images links. But it doesn't works well because some of the websites has different tags for the Images.

For Example:

```
<img alt="flixbus flixcharter" class="lazyload legal-module--image--10Gin" data-src="https://cdn.flixbus.de/assets/images-20180806/svg/charter.svg"/>

<img alt="dress with pinafore 24 cm" src="https://boneka-tradition.com/5956-home_default/dress-with-pinafore-24-cm.jpg"/>
```

and So on with a lot of different tags,

My Code:

```
for x in self.soup.find_all('img'):
    print(x['src'])
```

Each time I have to change the 'src' to the available tag in the user, Is there any way to get the IMG URL without entering the specific tag or anything to grab all the URL'S for multiple websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `or` short-circuit operator. For example: `dict.get(a) or dict.get(b)`, if `a` will exist, it will return `a` and not look at `b`, otherwise it will return `b`.

In your case:

```
...
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.find_all('img'):
    print(tag.get('data-src') or tag.get('src'))
```

output:

```
https://cdn.flixbus.de/assets/images-20180806/svg/charter.svg
https://boneka-tradition.com/5956-home_default/dress-with-pinafore-24-cm.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

`beautifulsoup` doesn't know anything about image URLs, only HTML attributes. So you'll have to check both `src` and `data-src` on your `img` elements, since both are allowed by the HTML5 spec

```py
for x in soup.find_all("img"):
    attr = "src" if hasattr(x, "src") else "data-src"
    print(x[attr])
```

Answer (score 0):

Created a list with the sources you are currently getting, if you get another peculiar  one you can just add it in the list and it will try to find it in the tag attributes.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """<img alt="flixbus flixcharter" class="lazyload legal-module--image--10Gin" data-src="https://cdn.flixbus.de/assets/images-20180806/svg/charter.svg"/>
<img alt="dress with pinafore 24 cm" src="https://boneka-tradition.com/5956-home_default/dress-with-pinafore-24-cm.jpg"/>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
sources = ["src", "data-src"]
for x in soup.find_all('img'):
    d = [y for y in x.attrs.keys() if y in sources]
    # 1st Iteration : ['data-src'], # 2nd Iteration : ['src']
    print(x.get(d[0]))
    # 1st print : https://cdn.flixbus.de/assets/images-20180806/svg/charter.svg
    # 2nd print : https://boneka-tradition.com/5956-home_default/dress-with-pinafore-24-cm.jpg
```